# Boxcast not working with Capsule Collider 2D in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D platform game where my character makes a ground check before jumping using Physics2D.BoxCast & some of the platforms have Capsule Collider 2D & others have Box Collider 2D.

Everything works fine with the Box Collider but when it comes to Capsule Collider, Boxcast is not responding & my character can spam jump on those platforms. Here's my code for ground check,

```
public bool isGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector3.down, castDist, ground);
    return raycastHit.collider != null;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? Any way to detect both BoxCollider & CapsuleCollider?

Comment: A cast detects any 2D collider so this can't be where the issue is ;) Is it on the correct `ground` layer?

Comment: Yes, I've checked with layer, it's in correct order.

Comment: I don't mean the order (sorting layer) but rather the layer you are using to filter the boxcast (`ground`)

Comment: I found the source of this issue & fixed it. See my answer, thanks for your response anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the `castDist` variable was causing the issue. It was set to `5` so the detection at bottom was far more than enough, reducing it to `0.1` solved the issue.